# i want to add Login success/failure message

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am trying to Add Login success/failure message in my Login.cshtml.cs file, but I don't know how to implement that (I'm a total newbie in this.) and when I use modelstate.errormessage/viewbag I doesn't show the message goes onto loading the page

Login Get Action

```
public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null) 
{ 
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) 
    {   
         Response.Redirect("/");
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ErrorMessage);
    }

    returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

    // Clear the existing external cookie to ensure a clean login process
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);

    ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

    ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
}
```

Login Post

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null) 
{ 
    returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {      
        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
          
            _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
            return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);            
        }
        else 
        { 
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt."); return Page(); 
        } 
}
```

Login view (its just normal identity default razor login view,i just fiddled with few bits nothing much)

```
  @page
  @model LoginModel
  @{
  ViewData["Title"] = "Log in";
  Layout = "~/Areas/Identity/Pages/_LRLayout.cshtml";
 }


<div class="col-md-10 offset-md9">
<section>
    <div class="login-form-icon">
        <i class="fas fa-user-circle 
      fa-9x text-secondary" style=" 
    margin: 0px 81px; padding: 0px 
     16px;"></i>
    </div>
    <form id="account" method="post">
        <div asp-validation- 
    summary="All" class="text-danger">. 
    </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp- 
  for="Input.Email"></label>
            <input asp- 
 for="Input.Email" class="form-control" 
 />
            <span asp-validation- 
  for="Input.Email" class="text- 
    danger">. 
   </span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp- 
   for="Input.Password"></label>
            <input asp- 
  for="Input.Password" class="form- 
   control" />
            <span asp-validation- 
for="Input.Password" class="text- 
 danger">. 
 </span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label asp- 
 for="Input.RememberMe">
                    <input asp- 
 for="Input.RememberMe" />
                    
 @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => 
 m.Input.RememberMe)
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" 
  class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Log 
 in</button>
        </div>

    </form>
</section>
</div>

@section Scripts {
<partial 
 name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

Help is appreciated

Thank you....

Comment: Please post your Login `View` also. We need to see how you are trying to display the messages on your view,

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to Add Login success/failure message in my Login.cshtml.cs
> file

In Login.cshtml.cs， the status of login success or failure has been judged by `if (result.Succeeded)`,  and if login fail will display the login failure information. Add login successfully  message,  then in _LoginPartial.cshtml in Layout,  `@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))` will judge the logged in user, there you can use `@TempData["Message"]` to display the message when the login is successful.

Login Post:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");

            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
                // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                    TempData["Message"] = "Login successfully !";
                    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                }
  else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt. Login Fail!");
                    return Page();
}
}
}
```

_LoginPartial.cshtml

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager

<ul class="navbar-nav">
@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a  class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage">Hello @User.Identity?.Name! @TempData["Message"]</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <form class="form-inline" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Logout" asp-route-returnUrl="@Url.Page("/", new { area = "" })" method="post" >
            <button  type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link text-dark">Logout</button>
        </form>
    </li>
}
else
{
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Register">Register</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login">Login</a>
    </li>
}
</ul>
```

result:

Login Successfuly:

[image]

Login fail:
[image]